# How to add a Thin Vertical Border Line (left side of each page) in PDF Docs

Tags: color, pdfpages, border

How to add a thin vertical border line (left side of each page) in PDF documents. 
Please see the attached image for more information[image: attached image].

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{29,57,127}

\backgroundsetup{
  position=current page.north west,
  color=myblue,
  nodeanchor=north west, 
  contents={\rule{10pt}{\paperheight}} 
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. While running I found this error ... May you have a look in this issue ... Thanks ... line 12: Package xkeyval Error: `nodeanchor' undefined in families `background'. }

Comment: @ibrahimkbd You're welcome. The error indicates that your version of the background package is outdated; you should update it. In the meantime, replace `node anchor=north west` with `anchor=below right`, and it should work. Please let me know if this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This uses the `\AddEverypageHook` macro of the `everypage` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{\textcolor{blue!70}{#3}}}}}
\atxy{0in}{0in}{\rule[-\paperheight]{4pt}{\paperheight}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-35]
\end{document}
```

[image]